# Error occurs when I rerun a tex file without closing the pdf file

Tags: errors, pdf

When we make a file, we write a tex file, run it, check the pdf file, fix the tex file, rerun it, and check the pdf file again. 
Whenever I rerun the file without closing previous version of pdf file, it occurs an error. If I close the pdf file, it works well. But it is bothering to close the pdf file every time. How can I fix it?
I am using Adobe X reader in Windows XP

Comment: Adobe Reader X doesn't allow the refresh of the opened files. So it is its fault if you get an error. The only way to achieve what you ask, I think, is to change the pdf reader. Try SumatraPDF. It is for Windows and it can be set up even for direct/inverse search

Comment: @Spike There is another (slightly more difficult) way: If the editor supports DDE commands, the editor could close the Adobe Reader and re-open it after compilation. TXC for example supports DDE commands (another hint: search for `acroviewR10`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I open PDF in Adobe Reader DC without locking the file from being updated by pdflatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288470/how-do-i-open-pdf-in-adobe-reader-dc-without-locking-the-file-from-being-updated)

Answer (score 11):

Adobe Reader X locks the file after opening it, so no other program is allowed to edit the PDF while open. 
This is why `pdflatex` gives you an error trying to overwrite the file.
Depending on how you compile your document (`interactive` or `non interactive` way), 
you could specify a new file for the resulting PDF, but this is quite annoyng. 
The best way to achieve this is to change the PDF viewer while you are working with LaTeX.
[SumatraPDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/) is a possibility on Windows (and allows direct/inverse search).
Alternatively, you could use a LaTeX editor equipped with an embedded reader, 
such as [TeXworks](http://www.texworks.org/), [Texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/) or [TeXstudio](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/),
which allow what you asked for, out of the box.