# Latex from Command Line Windows

Tags: windows

I switched from Mac to Windows recently and would like to continue to use Emacs as my editor. On my macbook I could make the pdf file from my tex file from the command line and open the pdf while the pdf file was open. It would rewrite it and then reopen the new version of the pdf. In windows pdflatex stops running and says that it can't write to the pdf file when it is open. Is there a way around this? Is it the pdf viewer I'm using or is it a problem with how Latex works in windows.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Adobe  Reader as a viewer, per chance?

Comment: Probably a bit of both. I’d just close the external PDF viewer and use the internal one with the editor.

Comment: Have you tried Sumatra?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I open PDF in Adobe Reader DC without locking the file from being updated by pdflatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288470/how-do-i-open-pdf-in-adobe-reader-dc-without-locking-the-file-from-being-updated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Sumatra PDF Reader (https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader.html)
It is a free pdf reader. It is not blocking write access for the opened pdfs and it automatically refreshes them.

Also, you can double click on a pdf file created with latex and it will "backtrack" to find the original tex file (to edit the latex code)